# 2D array formatting in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I'm using jq to reformat my files to be "nice and pretty". I'm using basic '.', but this is not working as I expect.

Let's say I have structure like this:

```
{ "foo": { "bar": { "baz": 123 }, 
"bislot": 
[[1,2,3,4,5],
[6,7,8,9,10],
[11,12,13,14,15]]
}}
```

and after reformatting with jq . I'm getting output like this:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "baz": 123
    },
    "bislot": [
      [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
      ],
      [
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10
      ],
      [
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "baz": 123
    },
    "bislot":
      [[1,2,3,4,5],
      [6,7,8,9,10],
      [11,12,13,14,15]]
  }
}
```

So for 2D arrays every item(array) should be in one line. Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: Why should it matter how the formatting of the JSON looks like?

Comment: There is no direct way to control that from `jq`

Comment: it's more readable in code review, there can be over 100 arrays like this so it's better to reduce number of lines in file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been pointed out already, from a JSON processor's perspective the formatting doesn't really matter. As you have noticed, `jq` by default pretty-prints its output. It also offers a `--compact-output` (or `-c`) option to output each JSON document into one line, which in your case would result in

```bash
jq -c . file.json
```

```json
{"foo":{"bar":{"baz":123},"bislot":[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]}}
```

If you care more about aesthetics than whether it is logically the same document or not, an easy way could be to encode all arrays within arrays as JSON, thus becoming strings, which when pretty-printing the whole document with `jq` won't be broken down anymore:

```bash
jq 'walk(arrays[] |= (arrays |= @json))' file.json
```

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "baz": 123
    },
    "bislot": [
      "[1,2,3,4,5]",
      "[6,7,8,9,10]",
      "[11,12,13,14,15]"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/gVoE_x1hFKw)

Going further, you could take the output from the previous call, read it line by line back into `jq`, decode lines with JSON-encoded arrays using `fromjson`, and output the modified lines (together masquerading as JSON document). This approach uses regex matching with look-ahead and look-behind to identify (the positions of) JSON-encoded arrays.

```bash
jq 'walk(arrays[] |= (arrays |= @json))' file.json \
| jq -Rr '(
    match("^\\s+(?=\"\\[)").length as $a
    | match("(?<=\\]\"),?$").offset as $b
    | .[:$a] + (.[$a:$b] | fromjson) + .[$b:]
  ) // .'
```

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "baz": 123,
      "baz2": 123
    },
    "bislot": [
      [1,2,3,4,5],
      [6,7,8,9,10],
      [11,12,13,14,15]
    ]
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DFotnPWZiSB)

Disclaimer: Although this outputs a valid JSON document for your sample input, this should still be regarded as an aesthetic printout. If the validity of your JSON document is a first-class concern, the actual formatting shouldn't really matter. `jq`'s default pretty-printer, and its compact equivalent generally should fit most needs.

Comment: your solution would probably be working but I can't use 'walk' function, we are using jq ver. 1.5 only.

Comment: @MarekZelek You could define `walk` as jq does itself in the [source code](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L273-L280), and prepend it to your code: `jq 'def walk(f): . as $in | if type == "object" then reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key ({}; . + {($key): ($in[$key] | walk(f))}) | f elif type == "array" then map(walk(f)) | f else f end; walk(arrays[] |= (arrays |= @json))' file.json | ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can consider combining `jq` with another tool (here `perl`):

```
jq . input.json | perl -0 -pe 's/(\[\s*)
                           (((\[[^\[\]]+\])[^\[\]]*)+)
                          /$v1=$1; $v2 = $2;
                           $v2 =~ s{\[[^\[\]]+\]}
                                   {$v=$&,($v =~ s[\s][]g),$v}egsx;
                           $v1 . $v2
                          /egsx'
```

Comment: your are close, but it also put items from 1D arrays in one line so it looks more like my original structure. https://pastebin.com/08Ug8Ym5
This should take affect only on 2D arrays.

Comment: Almost, but this time it works only on first array: https://pastebin.com/yvHHDtsc